# Install Failed - apt-get won't work

Tags: apt

I tried to install `php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux` from source using `apt-get` but that failed. Now what ever I want to remove or install using `apt-get`, it gives me error:

```
E: The package php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux needs to be 
reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How do I get rid of it?

**EDIT 2**

Same issue:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux*.deb
(Reading database ... 180639 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux 6.1.2.1-1 (using .../php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux_6.1.1-2_all.deb) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.
dpkg: error processing /home/aceph/Downloads/php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux_6.1.1-2_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 100
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 39: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: semodule: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/aceph/Downloads/php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux_6.1.1-2_all.deb
```

When I remove something:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docky
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I have Tomcat7 installed. Here's `$ java -version`

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT 1**

I run following, same error:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux needs
to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux
sudo apt-get update
```

Now every thing retain normal.

To install php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux you can download the binary(.deb) file by clicking [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Debian/php-java-bridge_6.1.2-1_beta/php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux_6.1.1-2_all.deb/download).

Now to install open your terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/php-java-bridge-j2ee-selinux*.deb
```

Comment: plz check Edit 2

Comment: `invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.`  Do you have tomcat installed?

Comment: Yes. It is Tomcat7

Comment: Its requesting tomcat5.5

Comment: Hmm. So I might need to downgrade. Leme find some solutions...

Comment: You might not im just trying some solutions I'll tell you when i do

Answer (score 0):

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 not found.
```

This means you don't have tomcat installed:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat
```

This will allow the installation of the package. You also have to check:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 39: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: semodule: not found
```

This is telling you it can't find the `selinux` module, which is supposed to be installed before hand:

```
sudo apt-get install policycoreutils
```

Then you can remove the package as usual.